# What's wrong with this piece of code? Scala - tuple as function type

Tags: scala, runtime-error

What's wrong with the following piece of code ? I'm trying to use a tuple (String, Int) as the type of input to the function `find_host`. The complier doesn't give me any errors but when I run the program I get one. What am I missing here?

```
  def find_host ( f : (String, Int) ) =     {
    case ("localhost", 80 ) => println( "Got localhost")
    case _  => println ("something else")
  }

  val hostport = ("localhost", 80)

  find_host(hostport)

      missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
  def find_host ( f : (String, Int) ) =     {
                                           ^
```

Comment: That's a compilation error, not a runtime error. Just to be clear. See the other answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a pattern match (your case statements here), you need to tell the compiler what to match on:

```
def find_host ( f : (String, Int) ) = f match {
...                                   ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Ah that fixed it. Why didn't the compiler not complain about this ? Just curious !

Comment: Don't know - it did complain for me.

Comment: Very strange. I'm using IntellJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

This code does fail compilation. IntelliJ's Scala support is not perfect; you can't count on it to find all compile errors.

This is what you get if you try it in the REPL:

```
scala>   def find_host ( f : (String, Int) ) =     {
     |     case ("localhost", 80 ) => println( "Got localhost")
     |     case _  => println ("something else")
     |   }
<console>:7: error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
         def find_host ( f : (String, Int) ) =     {
                                                   ^
```

Like Shadowlands's answer says, you're missing `f match` before the partial function.

But also, since this method returns `Unit`, don't define it with the equals symbol.

```
def find_host(f: (String, Int)) {
  f match {
    case ("localhost", 80) => println("Got localhost")
    case _  => println("something else")
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, these days everyone is saying *do* define it with the equals sign. Except for Rex Kerr.

Comment: There are long discussions on the ML about deprecating procedure syntax. Apparently it is a source of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

**Note: here you don't need to tell the compiler what to match.**

```
scala> def find_host: PartialFunction[(String, Int), Unit] = {
     |   case ("localhost", 80) => print("Got localhost")
     |   case _ => print("Something else")
     | }
find_host: PartialFunction[(String, Int),Unit]

scala> find_host(("localhost", 80))
Got localhost
```

Or this one:

```
scala> def find_host: ((String, Int)) => Unit = {
     |   case ("localhost", 80) => print("Got localhost")
     |   case _ => print("Something else")
     | }
find_host: ((String, Int)) => Unit

scala> find_host(("localhost", 80))
Got localhost
```

Comment: `val findHost = (_: Any) match { case ("localhost", 80) => println("Got localhost") }`